# phpMyAdmin causes computer to restart?

Tags: windows-8, phpmyadmin

This might sounds crazy, but on windows 8 I tried 3 browsers (Firefox, Chrome, And IE) and each time I went to:

`http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin` a message would show up:

"your pc ran into a problem and needs to restart windows 8"

I was helping a client with a problem and this happened 3 times in a row. Going to `http://127.0.0.1` or `google.com` works without crashing the computer.

I have installed this same version of phpMyAdmin on many computers and never ran into this issue.

What could be causing this?

Comment: copy the folder **C:\Windows\minidump** to your desktop, zip it and upload the zip to OneDrive.com/Dropbox and post a link here.

Comment: Found out they had spyware that randomly caused computer to restart. Removed that and it fixed problem.

Comment: ...and accept it.

Comment: I can accept in 6 hours

Answer (score 0):

Found out they had spyware that randomly caused computer to restart. Removed that and it fixed problem.